# ACF flexible content layout group for table of contents

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have an ACF flexible content field with a layout name of 'post_section' which has a group field called 'paragraph' with fields for 'id', 'title' and 'text'. In my component-post_section.php file i have the following php:

```
<?php if( have_rows('paragraph') ): ?>
<?php while( have_rows('paragraph' ) ): the_row(); ?>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="<?php the_sub_field('id'); ?>">
        <h2><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></h2>
      <?php the_sub_field('text'); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This produces the following which is fine:

[image]

But im trying to produce the following - a bootstrap accordion table of contents above with the titles of the two post_section titles:

[image]

This is my php:

```
<?php if( have_rows('paragraph') ): ?>
<?php while( have_rows('paragraph' ) ): the_row(); ?>
    <div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Table of Contents
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">        
            <p><a href="<?php the_sub_field('id'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="<?php the_sub_field('id'); ?>">
        <h2><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></h2>
      <?php the_sub_field('text'); ?>
    </div>
  </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, this is what i get:

[image]

Any ideas on how i can achieve what i want i.e an output of my title and text field fields for each paragraph BUT only a single output of the titles in the table of contents div like this?

[image]

Maybe i need to create a separate component php file for the accordion?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you will need 2 `while` loops. In the first one print the table of contents and in the second one the accordion

Comment: Ive tried that but it doesnt work wither.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you edit my code and give me the answer? Ive tried adding two while loops where i thought they needed to be but im obviously wrong as it just keeps repeating the table of contents per paragraph.

Comment: what bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: what you are showing in the last image is not an accordion ... it is just a table of contents with anchor links to the titles of the sections below. Is.that correct? This is what an accordion looks like and it doesn't look like that's what you need: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/#example

Comment: Im using version 4. It doesnt necessatily have to be an accordion, just a box which outputs the 2 titles is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question right, you simply want a single accordion dropdown to reveal a list of your flexible content paragraph sections?

The single accordion dropdown content is essentially a list of anchor links to navigate directly directly to your flexible content paragraph sections.

If this is the case, then see working example below of how to achieve this.

All of this code below must be run inside your post loop.

```html
<div class="container">

    <?php if(have_rows('paragraph')): ?>
        <div class="accordion" id="tableContentsAccordion">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="tableContents">
                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tableContentsList" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="tableContentsList">
                            Table of Contents
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div id="tableContentsList" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="tableContents" data-parent="#tableContentsAccordion">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <?php while(have_rows('paragraph')): the_row();
                            $title = get_sub_field('title');
                            ?>
                            <a href="#<?php echo sanitize_title($title); ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a><br/>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(have_rows('paragraph')): ?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php while(have_rows('paragraph')): the_row();
                $title = get_sub_field('title');
                ?>
                <div class="col-12" <?php echo $title ? 'id="' . sanitize_title($title) . '"' : ''; ?>>
                    <?php echo $title ? '<h2>' . $title . '</h2>' : ''; ?>
                    <?php the_sub_field('text'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

As mentioned in previous comments on your question, you need to run the `have_rows('paragraph')` statement twice in order to output flexible content paragraph sections content in two separate html locations.

You can actually combine all my code into a single `have_rows('paragraph')` statement, but only if your section content immediately follows your table of contents html.

If you want to put your table of contents in the sidebar or anywhere separate from your paragraph section output, then you will need to use `have_rows('paragraph')` twice.

---

### Update 1

So in response to your first comment, I created this example ACF flexible content field on a test environment.

Flexible content field named `paragraphs` and field location set to `Post` post type.

With a single block layout named `paragraph` with two sub fields `title` and `name`...

[image]

I then created a new `post` with this flexible content data...

[image]

I then ran this php code in my `single.php`...

```html
<?php

// get our header
get_header();

?>

<main>
    <div class="container">

        <?php if(have_posts()): ?>

            <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <h1 class="pb-2 my-4 border-bottom"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                <?php if(have_rows('paragraphs')): ?>
                    <div class="accordion" id="tableContentsAccordion">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header" id="tableContents">
                                <h2 class="mb-0">
                                    <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tableContentsList" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="tableContentsList">
                                        Table of Contents
                                    </button>
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tableContentsList" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="tableContents" data-parent="#tableContentsAccordion">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <?php while(have_rows('paragraphs')): the_row(); ?>
                                        <?php $title = get_sub_field('title'); ?>
                                        <a href="#<?php echo sanitize_title($title); ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a><br/>
                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if(have_rows('paragraphs')): ?>
                    <div class="row my-4">
                        <?php while(have_rows('paragraphs')): the_row(); ?>
                            <?php $title = get_sub_field('title'); ?>
                            <div class="col-12" <?php echo $title ? 'id="' . sanitize_title($title) . '"' : ''; ?>>
                                <?php echo $title ? '<h2>' . $title . '</h2>' : ''; ?>
                                <?php the_sub_field('text'); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</main>

<?php

// get our footer
get_footer();
```

And this is the tested output within the `<main>` html element...

[image]

This update code is the same as my first code example, but I've changed the flexible content field name from `paragraph` to `paragraphs` in this second update example, and I've also included the full `singe.php` post loop.

Not sure how my code outputted your `However` screenshot?

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but i get exactly the same output as my 3rd screenshot (above) where i say "However, this is what i get:"

Comment: @chappers see **Update 1** in my answer, hope this gives some clarity to my original answer. 

Comment: Thanks for your help @joshmoto but the issue is i want to add layouts between each paragraph. So for example, i might have a paragraph layout, then another layout and then another paragraph layout. If i do that following your code then i end up with a table of contents above each paragraph.